# Calculate upstream path

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geometric-network, rivers, utility-network

I have a river geometric network built that is fully operational with flow direction working.
In ArcMAP when I trace upstream I get a selected feature that I can convert into a feature class (Data > Export > Selected Features).

How do I do this in a model as I have 50,000 Flags?

Here is the model.
[image: Model is working]

***The output appears to be a "Ouput Group Layer Name". How do I get this to a feature class in the model above?***

[image]

In the help menu it states that I should use "*Make Feature Layer*" and "*Select Data*" but I have been unable to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output Group Layer Name is the name of the group layer that will store the results of the trace as a selected set.

Based on your scenario, there must be one feature layer (e.g. SourceFeatureLayer) inside that group layer that you have to a get a reference to to export it to a Feature Class.  You should use the name of output group layer concatenated to the name of your SourceFeatureLayer. To do this in model builder, use Calculate Valve tool and then Feature Class to Feature Class tool.

If you share your model and tell me the name of your source Featurel layer, then i will create a final model for you.